# Merging Text Into Specific Place in Textbox from Combobox Using .SelStart & .SelLength

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

As the title suggests, I'm trying to merge prefilled text values from a combobox into a specific place in a textbox on my form. **NOTE** Neither the form nor the textbox are bound to any data source.

I have a textbox (Me.EmailMessage) with text data. I'd like to be able to save my cursor place in the textbox, then click a combobox (cboFields) to select a field from a table, which is stored at cboFields.Column(1). After selecting the field, I'd like the textbox to merge the value of the field selected into the same place where my cursor was when the textbox loss focus to move to the dropdown box.

The logic goes like this:

1. Before Me.EmailMessage loses focus, the cursor position within Me.EmailMessage will be saved to a variable called vCursorPosition and the text value of Me.EmailMessage will be saved to a variable called vOriginalText.
2. After the user selects the text value from cboFields, the value of cboFields.Column(1) will be saved to a variable called vMergeText.
3. The focus will be set to Me.EmailMessage, and the value of Me.EmailMessage will be replaced with the value of vOriginalText.
4. The value of vMergeText will be inserted at the location stored in vCursorPosition.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
Dim vCursorPosition     As Long
Dim vOriginalText       As String
Dim vSelectionLength    As Long
Dim vMergeText          As String

Private Sub EmailMessage_AfterUpdate()
    vCursorPosition = Me.EmailMessage.SelStart
    vSelectionLength = Me.EmailMessage.SelLength
    vOriginalText = Me.EmailMessage.Text
End Sub

Private Sub cboFields_AfterUpdate()
    vMergeText = Me.cboFields.Column(1)
    Me.EmailMessage.SetFocus
    Me.EmailMessage.Text = vOriginalText ''ERROR HAPPENS HERE''
    Me.EmailMessage.SelStart = vCursorPosition
    Me.EmailMessage.SelLength = vSelectionLength
    Me.EmailMessage.SelText = vMergeText
End Sub
```

I'm getting this error when I run the above code:

`Run-time error '2115': The macro or function set to the BeforeUpdate or ValudationRule property for this field is preventing Microsoft Access from saving the data in the field.`

However, there is no code or macro set to the BeforeUpdate or ValidationRule property for Me.EmailMessage.

You can see where the code stalls out, above, where after the user has selected the text from cboFields.Column(1), the focus moves to Me.EmailMessage then attempts to set the value of Me.EmailMessage to the stored string value of vOriginalText.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

I was getting an error because I can't use the .Text property unless the control I was using it with has the focus. I tried this instead and it worked beautifully:

```
Dim vCursorPosition     As Long
Dim vOriginalText       As String
Dim vSelectionLength    As Long
Dim vMergeText          As String

Private Sub cboFields_AfterUpdate()
    vMergeText = Me.cboFields.Column(1)
    Me.EmailMessage = Left(vOriginalText, vCursorPosition - 1) & vMergeText & Mid(vOriginalText, vCursorPosition + vSelectionLength)
End Sub

Private Sub EmailMessage_AfterUpdate()
    vOriginalText = Me.EmailMessage
    vCursorPosition = Me.EmailMessage.SelStart
    vSelectionLength = Me.EmailMessage.SelLength
    
    If Me.Dirty Then
        DoCmd.RunCommand (acCmdSaveRecord)
    End If
End Sub
```